# How pass authorization in HTTP request connector in Mule4

Tags: dataweave, mulesoft, mule4

I have a need where I have to make Post request to a service with authorization, I am using HTTP request component of Mule4. However, I don't see place holder in HTTP request for passing credentials, ID, password. Any pointers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You case use the following docs to configure the desired:

https://docs.mulesoft.com/http-connector/1.5/http-request-ref#headers

https://docs.mulesoft.com/http-connector/1.5/http-authentication